In simple functions is 'const' or 'let' or 'var' even necessary
This is a Postman global function, but it's what I have for an example.  I have many of these types of examples in my code.
endpointUtils = {
    validateResponse: pm => {
        const responseData = pm.response.json();

        pm.test("Response field 'status' equals 'S'", () => {
            pm.expect(responseData.status).to.eql('S')
        })
    }
}

As matter of habit I define variables like 'responseData' with 'const'. I'm wondering in this circumstance if any modifier is necessary, be it 'const', 'let', or 'var'.   Would nothing do just as well?  It would greatly simplify the clutter in these small functions.  Am curious if this is violating some best practices at some level.  Within the scope of the function 'validateResponse', does it really matter?

If you never have another variable called responseData, and never want anyone else to approve your code reviews, sure. Try this for an example of why that's an issue: const foo = () => { bar = 1 }; foo(); console.log(bar);. Undeclared variables are globals. You also could never work in strict mode, which means you couldn't use ES Modules.

I take the hint and chuckled at your first sentence.  I'll keep the 'const' keyword... Didn't know that without it made it a global variable.  I was expecting the function scope to protected it.  All good to know.  Was refactoring and wondered about its significance within a function,

Postman has some different rules... I think.  Everything is working fine as it is.  Thank you.

@Zac Anger, you taught me something.  Thank you, very much.

You're welcome, no problem. I don't use Postman so I'm not sure what it's doing there, but I'm guessing it's just sending these user-defined functions to Node via Electron's IPC (I think it's an Electron app still?) and executing, maybe in a new vm context, so it wouldn't be settting use strict, which is why that would be fine.
